# How to get the equation of tangent plane when the point is an unknown?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Problem:

[image]

Solution:
[image]

I don't understand how they got the equation in the black box.

Here is my attempt:

$$\overrightarrow { \nabla  } F({ x }_{ 0 },{ y }_{ 0 },{ z }_{ 0 })=(2x-2y)\widehat { i } +(6y-2x)\widehat { j } +8z\widehat { k } \\ \overrightarrow { \nabla  } F({ x }_{ 0 },{ y }_{ 0 },{ z }_{ 0 })\cdot (x-{ x }_{ 0 },y-y_{ 0 },z-z_{ 0 })=0\\ (2x_{ 0 }-2y_{ 0 },6y_{ 0 }-2x_{ 0 },8z_{ 0 })\cdot (x-{ x }_{ 0 },y-y_{ 0 },z-z_{ 0 })=0\\ (2x_{ 0 }-2y_{ 0 })\cdot (x-x_{ 0 })+(6y_{ 0 }-2x_{ 0 })\cdot (y-y_{ 0 })+8z_{ 0 }(z-z_{ 0 })=0$$

Comment: Equation in a black box is just a value of gradient, not the entire equation of plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a normal to the surface. The equation that you've boxed is simply the gradient at $(x,y,z)$ from the previous line but with $(x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ (and simplified slightly).

To complete the exercise, you can set up equations to solve for $P = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ based on the known form of normal to planes parallel to the coordinate planes. For example, in part (a), note that the tangent plane at $P$ is parallel to the $xz$-plane if and only if it has the same normal vectors as the $xz$-plane. So its normal vectors are all of the form $c \widehat j$ for $c \neq 0$. So $\overrightarrow{\nabla}F(x_0,y_0,z_0) = 2(x_0-y_0)\widehat i + 2(3y_0-x_0)\widehat j + 8z_0 = c\widehat j$ for some $c\neq0$, from which we get (equating components)
\begin{align*}
2(x_0-y_0) &= 0\\
2(3y_0 - x_0) &= c\\
8z_0 &= 0.
\end{align*}
The rest of the solution is algebra (solving for $P$ in terms of $c$ and then resubstituting into the equation of the surface to solve for $c$).